# Default font briefly appears when sorting gridview

Tags: css, asp.net, gridview, fonts

While sorting the contents of an ASP.NET gridview control there is a split-second where the default browser font displays in place of the web font that I have declared in the CSS (specifically, Inconsolata). This causes a momentary grow-then-shrink resize of the page's other elements, making for a clunky user experience.

Is there any way to prevent this from happening with web fonts, and will a slower Internet connection just exaggerate the effect further?

Comment: This is known as FOUT. Flash Of Unstyled Text.  Your text is rendered before your font or css loads.  There are numerous ways to approach fixing this, some involving preloading the font... Do a google search on 'FOUT web fonts', and you'll find a solution.

Comment: Great, thanks - sometimes just knowing the right thing to google is the difficult part!  I'll see what gets turned up...